# Engel expansion

Tags: series-expansion, summation, integer-sequence

How do I do an [Engel expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EngelExpansion.html) in *Mathematica*?

And find the unique non-decreasing sequence  of positive integers $ \{ a_1 ,a_2,a_3,\dots \}$ , such
$$\frac{e}{\pi}=\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_1 a_2}+\frac{1}{a_1 a_2 a_3}+\cdots$$

Comment: what about the code in the mathematica section on http://oeis.org/A006784

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MathWorld article you linked to has a link to a notebook containing Weisstein's code for generating Engel expansions.

In any case, here is a slight simplification of Weisstein's code:

```
engel[x_, n_Integer?Positive] := 
      Nest[Append[#, Ceiling[1/(x - Total[1/FoldList[Times, #]])/Times @@ #]] &,
           {}, n]
```

Test:

```
engel[E/π, 27]
   {2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 23, 43, 58, 30503, 32703, 44621, 51291, 479922, 781181, 2136095,
    2435396, 2600287, 2860451, 12557067, 35938396, 37552004, 75289454, 109334609,
    321224695, 336383475, 451039452, 586390841}
```

Check:

```
Total[1/FoldList[Times, %]] - E/π // N
   0.
```

Answer (score 7):

The code at [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A006784) works for me:

```
 EngelExp[A_, n_] := 
 Join[Array[1 &, Floor[A]], 
 First@Transpose@
 NestList[{Ceiling[1/Expand[#[[1]] #[[2]] - 1]], 
 Expand[#[[1]] #[[2]] - 1]} &, {Ceiling[1/(A - Floor[A])], 
 A - Floor[A]}, n - 1]]

 res = EngelExp[N[E/Pi, 500000], 27]
```

returns:

`{2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 23, 43, 58, 30503, 32703, 44621, 51291, 479922,
781181, 2136095, 2435396, 2600287, 2860451, 12557067, 35938396,
37552004, 75289454, 109334609, 321224695, 336383475, 451039452,
586390841}`

Test:

```
 Sum[1/Apply[Times, res[[1 ;; j]]], {j, 1, Length[res]}] - E/Pi // N
```

returns `0`. (meaning it's numerically close to zero; for higher precision use `N[(expression),(n_digit_precision)]`)